# How can I reset hard all branches in git

Tags: git, git-reset

How do I reset my all local branches, one time to be just like the branches in the remote repository?

I have 42 branches in my local repository, but I have just 21 branches in my remote repository. I don't need the other branches, I just need the 21 branches (with same name in local and remote).

I know

```
git fetch origin 
git reset --hard origin/master
```

but I want all 21 branches to together reset hard to the state in origin, and all other branches deleted that are not in origin.

Comment: Just delete the repository and clone a new one from origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use shell scripting if you are on Unix.

This will first delete *all* your local branches, and then create all branches from origin.

```shell
# make sure we are currently on no branch, so every branch can be deleted
git checkout --detach master

# delete all local branches
git branch | grep -v "HEAD detached" | xargs git branch -D

# re-create all branches from origin
while read b; do git branch ${b#origin/} $b; done < <(git branch -r | grep 'origin/')

# check out the new master
git checkout master
```